# What makes a locus in the complex plane a contour?

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

The question is pretty straightforward: **What makes a locus in the complex plane a contour?**

I read through the *Wolfram MathWorld* pages for both a [contour](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Contour.html) and [the Cauchy integral formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CauchyIntegralFormula.html) (the page about residue theorem was too lofty for me) but neither of these define any criteria.

I completely understand that the contour is the curve in the complex plane that is the **domain of integration for a line integral** of a complex-valued function. I am also under the impression that a locus must be **closed** to be a contour, but I am not sure.

Comment: I believe I may have used tags [tag:complex-analysis] and [tag:complex-integration] inappropriately; I welcome corrections to this.

Comment: In complex analysis you need : $\int_a^b f(z)dz$ and $ \int_\gamma f(z)dz$ where $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$, $f$ is an analytic function, and $\gamma$ is a (piecewise) $C^1$ finite-length curve, sometimes infinite-length. A closed curve means $\gamma(0) = \gamma(1)$. Contour often means closed curve. In some sense, the concatenation of closed curves is still a closed curve.